# To remove base url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a python script to extract the `href` value from all links on a given web page:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://kteq.in/services")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output which includes both external and internal links:

```
index
index
#
solutions#internet-of-things
solutions#online-billing-and-payment-solutions
solutions#customer-relationship-management
solutions#enterprise-mobility
solutions#enterprise-content-management
solutions#artificial-intelligence
solutions#b2b-and-b2c-web-portals
solutions#robotics
solutions#augement-reality-virtual-reality`enter code here`
solutions#azure
solutions#omnichannel-commerce
solutions#document-management
solutions#enterprise-extranets-and-intranets
solutions#business-intelligence
solutions#enterprise-resource-planning
services
clients
contact
#
#
#
https://www.facebook.com/KTeqSolutions/
#
#
#
#
#contactform
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
index
services
#
contact
#
iOSDevelopmentServices
AndroidAppDevelopment
WindowsAppDevelopment
HybridSoftwareSolutions
CloudServices
HTML5Development
iPadAppDevelopment
services
services
services
services
services
services
contact
contact
contact
contact
contact
None
https://www.facebook.com/KTeqSolutions/
#
#
#
#
```

I want to remove external links that have a full URL like `https://www.facebook.com/KTeqSolutions/` while keeping links like `solutions#internet-of-things`. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Sorry, what's a "base link"?

Comment: What did you try already? Please supply a minimal example

Comment: A base URL is, basically, the consistent part of your web address.

Comment: I want to remove https://www.facebook.com/KTeqSolutions/ from the above output

Comment: So you want to remove all lines that begin with `https` ?  Regex would do fine here.

Comment: I clarified the question to state the problem and your desired outcome more clearly and added some relevant tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can try something like:

```
l = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
    l.append(link.get('href'))
l = [x for x in l if "www" not in x] #or 'https'
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies.I got output.

Comment: @S.Nandhini you are welcome :) if an answer is what you were looking for,  consider to accept it by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: But you have to think about all possibilities like `http://`, `https://`, `file:///` and so on. And it does not work with ports e.g. `:8000`, `:4567`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse_url` from the `requests` module.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/KTeqSolutions/'

requests.urllib3.util.parse_url(url)
```

gives you

```
Url(scheme='https', auth=None, host='www.facebook.com', port=None, path='/KTeqSolutions/', query=None, fragment=None)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.